# Creating stub for dependence class's under test

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, reflection

Good day, everyone! I have a little question about testing and generating a stub for dependence through reflection. So let's assume I have  a class named UnderTest:

```
class UnderTest{
/*field*/ 
SomeLogic someLogic; 
/*method, that i testing*/
List<MyObject> getCalculatedObjects(params) {/*logic,based on result getSomeStuff of someLogic*/    }
} 
class SomeLogic { 
List<String> getSomeStuff(String param) { /*Some complex and slow code, actually  don't want test this code, and want to use some reflection invocation handler*/ }
}
```

For me it's important to not change legacy code, which doesn't design for testing. And i don't have any reason, except testing to make SomeLogic as an interface and so on. 
I can't remember how to handle method invocation of someLogic using reflection. But google search isn't helping me.

Class MainAPI is... main api of my module. NetworkProvider long open stream operation, that's why i want to stub it, on my local files. But don't using directly reference on NetworkProvider. Again sorry for my English.

```
public class MainAPI {
    private final XPath xPath;
    private final ItemParser itemParser;
    private final ListItemsParser listItemsParser;
    private final DateParser dateParser;
    private final HtmlCleanUp htmlCleanUp;

    private final NetworkProvider networkProvider;


    public MainAPI(XPath xPath, ItemParser itemParser, ListItemsParser listItemsParser, DateParser dateParser, HtmlCleanUp htmlCleanUp, NetworkProvider networkProvider) {
        this.xPath = xPath;
        this.itemParser = itemParser;
        this.listItemsParser = listItemsParser;
        this.dateParser = dateParser;
        this.htmlCleanUp = htmlCleanUp;
        this.networkProvider = networkProvider;
    }

    public MainAPI() throws XPathExpressionException, IOException {
        dateParser = new DateParser();
        xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        networkProvider = new NetworkProvider();
        listItemsParser = new ListItemsParser(xPath, dateParser, item -> true);
        itemParser = new ItemParser(xPath, dateParser, networkProvider);
        htmlCleanUp = new HtmlCleanUpByCleaner();
    }

    public List<Item> getItemsFromSessionParsing(SessionParsing sessionParsing) {
        listItemsParser.setCondition(sessionParsing.getFilter());
        List<Item> result = new ArrayList<>();
        Document cleanDocument;
        InputStream inputStream;
        for (int currentPage = sessionParsing.getStartPage(); currentPage <= sessionParsing.getLastPage(); currentPage++) {
            try {
                inputStream = networkProvider.openStream(sessionParsing.getUrlAddressByPageNumber(currentPage));
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
            cleanDocument = htmlCleanUp.getCleanDocument(inputStream);
            List<Item> list = null;
            try {
                list = listItemsParser.getList(cleanDocument);
            } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
            for (Item item : list) {
                inputStream = null;
                try {
                    inputStream = networkProvider.openStream("http://www.avito.ru" + item.getUrl());
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    break;
                }
                cleanDocument = htmlCleanUp.getCleanDocument(inputStream);
                try {
                    item.setDescription(itemParser.getDescription(cleanDocument));
                } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            result.addAll(list);
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public class NetworkProvider {
    private final ListCycleWrapper<Proxy> proxyList;

    public NetworkProvider(List<Proxy> proxyList) {
        this.proxyList = new ListCycleWrapper<>(proxyList);
    }

    public NetworkProvider() throws XPathExpressionException, IOException {
        this(new ProxySiteParser().getProxyList(new HtmlCleanUpByCleaner().getCleanDocument(new URL("http://www.google-proxy.net").openStream())));
    }

    public int getSizeOfProxy() {
        return proxyList.size();
    }

    public InputStream openStream(String urlAddress) throws MalformedURLException {
        URL url = new URL(urlAddress);

        while (!proxyList.isEmpty()) {
            URLConnection con = null;
            try {
                con = url.openConnection(proxyList.getNext());
                con.setConnectTimeout(6000);
                con.setReadTimeout(6000);
                return con.getInputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                proxyList.remove();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which mocking API are you using? How does UnderTest get its reference to SomeLogic?

Comment: I don't use any testing frameworks except JUnit. SomeLogic created inside field. I need to know, how to use reflection for handling invocation in complex case, like that, without setter of SomeLogic.

Comment: Show us the code. We need to know how the someLogic variable is initialized to give an answer. And consider using a mocking API, since you want to mock. That's what they're for, and they do it well. I personally like Mockito.

Comment: InvocationHandler is require object for handle. Hm... maybe it's impossible? But groovy have stubFor/mockFor class, that can help me, but they require that UnderTest was groovy class.

Comment: We can't help you without seeing the code. If you don't provide it, I'll vote to close your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the dependencies of your class to tests are injectable using its constructor, so there shouldn't be any problem to stub these dependencies and injecting the stubs. You don't even need reflection. For example, using Mockito:

```
NetworkProvider stubbedNetworkProvider = mock(NetworkProvider.class);
MainAPI mainApi = new MainAPI(..., stubbedNetworkProvider);
```

You can also write a stub by yourself if you want:

```
NetworkProvider stubbedNetworkProvider = new NetworkProvider(Collections.emptyList()) {
    // TODO override the methods to stub
};
MainAPI mainApi = new MainAPI(..., stubbedNetworkProvider);
```

Comment: Thanks! But i wrote in topic, that don't want using directly reference on NetworkProvider. Yes, i trying design testable classes, but also want to learn using some techniques for severely tested code. I'm trying to find an analogy of groovy's StubFor.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. The MainAPI class uses a NetworkProvider. So any stub you create, whatever the way you create it, must be an instance of NetworkProvider. Do you really understand what a stub is?

Comment: Let me explain myself again. I am learning TDD, (by Kent Beck), and all my app covered by tests, except main api class, this class is composition of logic units. And i can't imagine, how to test this code (main api), if it don't have constructor initializes/property setter access. I read groovy/grails book (Apress) and there i found StubFor and MockFor classes, that have method use, and no need to have directly reference for stub object. But it's work only for groovy class.

Comment: It **does** have a constructor which initializes the properties. And all mocking frameworks have methods to create stubs. Or you can create them by yourself as I showed in the answer. It seems you're stuck on Groovy's stubFor(), although you're not using Groovy. Learn Mockito, which does the same thing for Java.